# Fine Grained Logging when using CocoaLumberJack in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoalumberjack

I want to be able to open debug logging level for a specific file in my iOS application. We are using CocoaLumberJack in Swift as the logging framework. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/FineGrainedLogging.md), this is possible in Objective C, but I could not find any documentation regarding Swift. Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out how to do that. I did that by creating another enum:

```
public enum CustomLogFlags : UInt{
    case test = 0b0100000
}
```

And then set the log level:

```
DDLog.logLevel = DDLogLevel(rawValue: DDLogLevel.error.rawValue | CustomLogFlags.test.rawValue) ?? DDLogLevel.error
```

Now you can log messages using the new log level:

```
let logLevel = DDLogFlag(rawValue: CustomLogFlags.test.rawValue)
let logMsg = DDLogMessage(message: message(), level: logLevel, flag: flag, context: 0,
                    file: file, function: function, line: line,
                    tag: tag, options: DDLogMessageOptions(rawValue: 0), timestamp: nil)
DDLog.log(logAsync, message: logMsg)
```